# Cannot load show.bs.modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

i've tried every post about send data to modal in stack overflow but it still doesn't work. In console just printed "javascript oke" but when i click and modal opened, text "opened" not showing

**Button**

```
    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-simple btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-kode="code" data-namakode ="name_code" data-target="#edit">
                                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
</button>
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal Edit -->
<div class="modal" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{{route('tes')}}" method="post">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Kode</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalkode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Nama Kode</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalnamakode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"
                            style="margin-right: 10px">Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save Change</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  End Modal Edit -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
            console.log("javascript oke");
            $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                console.log("opened");
                // var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                //
                // var code = button.data('kode') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                // var code_name = button.data('namakode') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                //
                // // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
                // // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
                // var modal = $(this)
                // modal.find('.modal-body #modalkode').val(code)
                // modal.find('.modal-body #modalnamakode').val(code_name)
            });

</script>
```

[image: This is what happened in my web]

i'm actually want to send data from edit button to modal, but i tested javascript to report when modal showed is not working so i comment it

Comment: I have add all required such as JQuery, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try another way like

in html call function onclick of your edit button

```
 <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-simple btn-xs" onclick="editData()">
              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
 </button>
```

then write function in script for showing modal and process your data like

```
function editData(){
    $("#edit").modal("show");
    // do your stuff here 
}
```

it might be help you.

Comment: can i send data-foo from onclick? i want to send data from edit when clicked

Comment: yes you can send it as a parameter like onclick=editData(data) and take same parameter in function defination

Comment: your welcome, if it is helpful to you please accept this answer as true answer to help others:)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I tested my code on https://codepen.io/ and it works fine. i found the problem is on javascript template so i import in last jquery.js and bootstrap.js
I hope it can help the other who face same problem

Comment: You should have included direct link to your codepen that showed you solved the error, I am facing similar issue and I was hoping your code would lead to a pen but it led to Codepen's landing page instead.